# How to call postgresql methods from console application VS2015?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, postgresql, visual-studio-2015

I have created a new console application project.

I copied source `"Example Program 1"` [from this link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/libpq-example.html).

Then I go to "Project properties`"->C/C++->General->"Additional Include Directories"` and add  path `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\include\".`

Then I go to "Project properties"`->Linker->General->"Additional Library Directories"` and add path `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\lib".`

Then I go to `"Project properties"->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies"` and add name of the file `"libpq.lib".`

And then I compiled it.

```
    1>------ Сборка начата: проект: ConsoleApplication1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQconnectdb в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQfinish в функции "void __cdecl exit_nicely(struct pg_conn *)" (?exit_nicely@@YAXPAUpg_conn@@@Z)
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQstatus в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQerrorMessage в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQexec в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQresultStatus в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQntuples в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQnfields в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQfname в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQgetvalue в функции _main
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ _PQclear в функции _main
1>C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.dll : fatal error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 11
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Compiler commands:

> /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\include\" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"Debug\" /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pch"

Linker commands:

> /OUT:"C:\Users\test\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Users\test\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "libpq.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /IMPLIB:"C:\Users\test\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Users\test\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\ConsoleApplication1.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\lib" /TLBID:1

What I missed?

Comment: #pragma comment (lib, "libpq.lib") ??

Comment: instead of playing guess my error, can you post the entire error message.  LNK2019 is an unresolved external, and the identity of of the external might help in providing a solution.

Comment: Thanks.  Ok, so it appears that VS can find the implementations for the various postgresql functions.  Can you confirm that both `libpq.lib` and `libpq.dll` are in the library directory (if I recall correctly, the *.lib is in the library directory and the *.dll is in the bin directory).  If not, could you try copying the *.dll to the lib directory and recompiling?

Comment: @thurizas, Yes, I can confirm it. Directory /lib/ has both *.lib and *.dll files. By the way, at home on the other PC I don't have such trouble. I think it comes from environment or compiler. May be bad VS installation. At home I tried all steps with minGW and it was good.

Comment: nitpick: They're not really methods, they're functions, since they aren't part of a class. How sure are you that you're really linking to `libpq.lib`? this looks like it's probably missing. Show the compiler and linker command lines from the VS logs please.

Comment: @Craig Ringer, I add compiler and linker commands, but since I could do it on my other PC, I think it's trouble with something other. May be bad installation VS.